# Missing disk space?

Tags: filesystem, disk

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running from a single EXT4 partition on /dev/sda2 mounted at filesystem root, which shows in Disks as 1000Gb with 53Gb free:

[image: Disks utility]

But my system tells me it's low on disk space. Choosing File System Properties from a file manager (running as root), disk usage shows 228.9GB used with 3.1GB free.

Where did the other 700-odd GB go?

The System Monitor Filesystems tab also shows root filesystem as 982GB with 3.1GB free:

[image: System Monitor]

Running Baobab as root, I see the same root filesystem size in the device list:

[image: Baobab List]

But when I open "Filesystem root" device in the Baobab analyser screen, the size is reported as 229GB:

[image: Baobab analyser]

Grateful for any enlightenment... Thanks Nik

Comment: There is 5% root reserve on ext4. So it looks correct.

Comment: All analysis was done as root, so permissions is not likely to be the problem as far as I understand it.  My own disk usage corresponds with the 230GB disk size, which is why I want to know where the other 700GB went.  To simplfy - can anyone explain the apparent discrepancy in the two Baobab screenshots?  I'm interested in the "improperly cloned drive" suggestion, as I think the system drive on this machine was cloned, probably from a smaller one.  But the EXT4 partition occupies the full 1000GB, so why is only 230GB available to the filesystem?

Comment: In case it's useful, GParted reports the partition size as 931GB with 49GB free - so similar to Baobab. If this drive was cloned from a 230GB drive using Clonezilla, and this is limiting the usable space in the filesystem to 230GB even though the  partition is far larger, is there any way to fix it so that the whole partition is available to the filesystem?